# Kext driver is not responding after manual reset USB device on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, usb, driver, iokit, kernel-extension

I'm working with Bluetooth headset connected to the computer with Mac OS X operating system via USB.

I have application running in User space and also kext driver that works with headset by sending device requests and reading/writing pipes.

To change headset's settings I call IOUSBDevice::DeviceRequest(...), but to apply these settings I need to reboot the headset's chip.

The problem is when chip is rebooted after sending special device request from kext driver, the functions stop(IOService* provider) and free(void) are not called. So device disappears in the system for a second, but driver stays in the working state: I can't unload this driver:

```
bash-3.2# kextunload -b VXiCorp.USBDriver
(kernel) Can't unload kext VXiCorp.USBDriver; classes have instances:
(kernel)     Kext VXiCorp.USBDriver class VXiCorp_USBDriver has 1 instance.
Failed to unload VXiCorp.USBDriver - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
```

Also when headsets appears after rebooting (and even when I connect other usb headsets), functions start() and probe() are not called. So I can't work with headsets until rebooting the OS.

How can I reboot the headset and have kext driver working correctly?

I've tried to send reboot request from user space using IOUSBDeviceInterface300::DeviceRequest but it didn't help. Maybe I need to stop and free driver instance manually before rebooting headset, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

I't will be better to communicate with device from user space without using kext files, but here the problem is I can't get IOUSBInterfaceInterface300 to have read/write pipes functionality. I have IOUSBDeviceInterface300 and when I'm trying to call IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService I receice error kIOReturnUnsupported - 0x2c7 (unsupported function).

```
IOUSBFindInterfaceRequest request;

request.bInterfaceClass = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare;
request.bInterfaceSubClass = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare;
request.bInterfaceProtocol = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare;
request.bAlternateSetting = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare;

if ((*device)->CreateInterfaceIterator(device, &request, &iterator) != kIOReturnSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "[!] Failed to create interface iterator\n");
    return NULL;
}

while ((service = IOIteratorNext(iterator)) != 0)
{
    if (IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService(service, kIOUSBInterfaceUserClientTypeID, kIOCFPlugInInterfaceID, &plugin, &score) == kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

I've checked this thread http://lists.apple.com/archives/usb/2008/Mar/msg00001.html but codeless kext didn't help me.

Also I can't call IOUSBDeviceInterface300::OpenDevice or IOUSBDeviceInterface300::SetConfiguration, it looks like standart osx drivers open my device immediately after connecting.

So could you suggest the way to avoid the issue with device rebooting?

The part of ioreg output:

```
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 11>
  +-o VMware7,1  <class IOPlatformExpertDevice, id 0x10000010f, registered, mat$
    +-o AppleACPIPlatformExpert  <class AppleACPIPlatformExpert, id 0x100000110$
    | +-o PCI0@0  <class IOACPIPlatformDevice, id 0x10000012b, registered, matc$
    | | +-o AppleACPIPCI  <class AppleACPIPCI, id 0x100000195, registered, matc$
    | |   +-o PE50@16  <class IOPCIDevice, id 0x100000175, registered, matched,$
    | |   | +-o IOPP  <class IOPCI2PCIBridge, id 0x1000001e9, registered, match$
    | |   |   +-o S1F0@0  <class IOPCIDevice, id 0x100000176, registered, match$
    | |   |     +-o AppleUSBXHCI  <class AppleUSBXHCI, id 0x1000001fd, register$
    | |   |       +-o VXi B350-XT@16310000  <class IOUSBDevice, id 0x100000460,$
    | |   |       | +-o IOUSBInterface@2  <class IOUSBInterface, id 0x100000465$
    | |   |       +-o VXi B350-XT@16310000  <class IOUSBDevice, id 0x100000483,$
    | |   |         +-o IOUSBInterface@0  <class IOUSBInterface, id 0x100000486$
    | |   |         +-o IOUSBInterface@2  <class IOUSBInterface, id 0x100000488$
    | |   |         +-o VXiCorp_USBDriver  <class VXiCorp_USBDriver, id 0x10000$
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualising your device & driver hierarchy, so it'd be useful to have the relevant subtree of the output of `ioreg` - could you add that to the question please?

Comment: Thanks for trying understand, it is a hot issue for me. I've added subtree of ioreg. Please ask me if you need other info.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions here, but I'll try to answer a few:

- If the `IOUSBDevice` object is being terminated as a result of resetting the device, and your driver is not being stopped, then it is most likely blocking termination in some way. I suggest overriding the `terminate` family of methods and adding some logging to them. If removing the kext is failing, you're probably `retain`ing one or more objects too often. Don't permanently retain your provider object, for example. If in doubt, show us the ioreg state before and after the reset.
- For many USB devices or interfaces, it's usually not a great idea to access them from multiple clients simultaneously. This applies to concurrent access from both a kext and userspace. Try to access it either from only user space or only the kext.
- I'm not sure why `IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService` is failing in this case, but it could be to do with your codeless kext if you have one. Posting that would probably help.